# prevent javascript setInterval function stacking up

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a function that runs on a click event that uses javascript's setIterval for some of my animations (i'm doing a game) so the problem is that if a user clicks while the animation is still displaying (setInterval is still executing) the setInterval is stacking up in the event stack or that is what I found out thus either crushing my game or running twice as fast (the animation). My question is is there any way to prevent event stacking? I do not want the setInterval to stack up on the previous setInterval and so on. I know that I could use clearInterval function like so:

```
  var timerInterval = setInterval(drawPlayerRunning, 50);
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
```

but it does not really work as I want it to, because what if user clicks many times while the function is still is executing, the clearInterval will only get rid of last event of the event stack leaving all the previous ones still in the "game". Any idea how to prevent this event stack up, or at least removing them efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a flag that monitors the interval state:
1)

```
var isIntervalInProgress = false;
setInterval(function()
{
  if ( isIntervalInProgress )
    return false;

  isIntervalInProgress = true;

  drawPlayerRunning();

  isIntervalInProgress = false;

}, 50);
```

or just a timeout that will run itself once it's finished:
2)

```
var func = function()
{
  setTimeout(function()
  {
    drawPlayerRunning();
    func();
  }, 50)
}
```

whichever you like

Comment: This is not gonna work, because I want player to move through a tile based map, and once he clicks on a tile i want to show animation of a point floating over his head, and i want many simultanous animations like that.. dont want to wait until first animation is finished

Comment: after some time of experimenting your answer was actually very helpful

Comment: The first solution (isIntervalInProgress flag) will not work. JavaScript is not multithreaded. Use `(function run() { setTimeout(run, 50); draw(); }());`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame). It is designed with games in mind, and if your code happens to be too slow, it will reduce your frame rate accordingly (from 60 fps to 30 fps for instance). But it won't stack-up events.

Edit: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question. Let me try again.

You should have only one `draw` function which is called every few milliseconds (set the interval up with `requestAnimationFrame(draw)`).

A click should not add a new interval, but rather create a `floatingAnimation` object and add it to the list of objects to render. All animation objects will be rendered by the `draw` function everytime the browser calls `draw`. In the arguments passed to `draw`, there will be a timestamp. Use this timestamp minus the creation date of `floatingAnimation` to determine how to draw the floating thing above the character.

Comment: it seems like it's not supported in all browsers (Opera) but i guess if there is no other option i'll take a look into it