# Meteor setInterval stacking

Tags: meteor

I am using Meteor.setInterval to count up to keep track of a players "action points" in a game.  When they use an action (like attacking), it will decrease the amount.  However, when an event is triggered(attacking) it updates players profile on my DB which triggers the setInterval to stack each time the DB is updated.  It starts to counter faster and faster.  *edit* This is the issue.  I don't want it to count faster.  I want only one interval to be running.

This was the closest solution I could find:
[prevent javascript setInterval function stacking up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349576/prevent-javascript-setinterval-function-stacking-up)

Didn't quite work and I couldn't find a different way to arrange the flags to only have one setInterval going.

Heres my helper:  Each player has a different regen which is pulled from their profile.  I've substituted fixed numbers for the interval and did a Session.get() when the stacking occurs, it stays the same.  Instead of numbers I was just adding 'x' so it looks like a loading bar.

```
apTicker:function() {
  Session.set('apRegen', Meteor.user().profile.apRegen);
  Meteor.setInterval(function () {
    if (Session.get('ap').length < 25) {
      Session.set('ap', Session.get('ap')+"x");
      }
  }, Session.get('apRegen'))
},
```

Thank you.

Comment: So what you want is to be able to use only one setInterval to update the player's AP? Or do you want to be able to use multiple setIntervals to have somewhat of an acceleration in the AP regen? Plus, you are doing this on the client, while it seems like a critical part of your game and thus may have to be done on the server (to avoid cheating. Someone could type `Session.set('ap', <someCrazyValue>)` in the console!)

Comment: I'm new to Meteor and using auto publish and insecure.  I'm just learning to use Methods server side to update the DB.  This is currently client side.  And yes, only one setInterval and I do *not* want the acceleration. I could just pull the apRegen from the DB instead of using a Session.  I got caught up in using them. *edit* thanks for the heads up about security.  I want things to run properly right now and worry about security later.  Is it easier if I run this server side? Will updates to the DB not have an effect because it's no longer client?

Comment: If I had a simple setInterval client side in a helper that counts from 1 and adds 1 every second.  I assume when I update the DB it will stack and continue to stack every time I change the DB (in my example attack and Hp changes)?  I mean to ask, it's not what Im trying to do, rather because the helper runs again when I change the DB, causing stacking issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
var apTickerInterval; //To keep track of the interval
Session.set('apRegen', Meteor.user().profile.apRegen);
//...
apTicker : function()
{
  if(apTickerInterval)
    Meteor.clearInterval(apTickerInterval);

  apTickerInterval = Meteor.setInterval(function () {
    if (Session.get('ap').length < 25) {
      Session.set('ap', Session.get('ap')+"x");
    }
  }, Session.get('apRegen'));
}
```